# What is the theoretical maximal total of material for the insufficient material draw?

Tags: problems, draw, records

The insufficient mating material rule says that the game is immediately declared a draw if there is no way to end the game in checkmate. This usually happens in KB vs K or KN vs K endgames. However, based on the definition, it is theoretically possible to have more materials while checkmating is theoretically impossible, such as the following:

[image]

So what is the theoretical maximal total of material for the insufficient material draw? Here I am only asking legal positions; so adding a few white light coloured bishop to my example will not count.

Comment: This isn't really "insufficient material"; it's a "dead position". Material would be more than sufficient if there was any way to get it unstuck.

Comment: Check out https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18699/maximum-number-of-pieces-on-board-in-dead-position - does that answer the question?

Comment: @DM, I thought "insufficient material" means checkmate is theoretically impossible?

Comment: @DM, Yes, thank you for the link!

Comment: The confusion exists because "insufficient material" exists in USCF rules, and "dead position" exists in FIDE rules. They are similar but different.

Comment: You can give each player both rooks, and still the position is dead.

Comment: @Aganju, if white moves his rook to b2, black can capture it and possibly win the game.

Comment: you are right, of course. I thought about it hard, but it seems my subconscious still silently removed obviously stupid moves, so I never saw it.